# What determines when a React (functional) component is rerendered?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-functional-component, react-tsx

For some context, I'm making a game board where you can place pieces by selecting one from a different component, then clicking on a square on the board. Here's the general structure:

```
Game
  |- GameGrid
  |    |- Square
  |- PieceSelection
```

I have a state in `Game` that contains what is currently displayed on the `GameGrid`. Another state holds the currently selected piece. I pass down a function to `Square` which tells `Game` the ID of a square whenever it is clicked. Then, `Game` has the following handler function:

```
// Inside Game component:

function handlePiecePlacement(squareID: number) {
        
    // Conditions to check if valid placement...

    let newDisplay = currDisplay;
    newDisplay[squareID] = currSelectedPiece;
    setCurrDisplay(newDisplay);
}
```

This function gets passed as a prop to `GameGrid` which is then given to each `Square` in `GameGrid`.

The problem I have is that whenever this function is called (when a square is clicked) to update the current `display`, my `GameGrid` component is not being rerendered, so there is no visible change on the page, even though the `display` state has been updated. **Do I need to somehow signal to `GameGrid` that it needs to be rerendered? **My `Game` component returns the following pattern:

```
// Inside Game component:

return (
    <div className='game-wrapper'>
        <div className="grid-wrapper">
            <GameGrid display={currDisplay} handleMove={handlePiecePlacement}/>
        </div>
        <div className="side-wrapper">
            <PieceSelection submitClicked={handleClickToSelectPiece} currSelected={currSelectedPiece}/>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Note: there are a few other components in these wrappers but they shouldn't be relevant.

One other thing: I have another function to change the currently selected piece when the `PieceSelection` component receives a click event, and for some reason, the function for that rerenders the `GameGrid`. Both this piece selection handler and the update display handler are in the `Game` component. Why does this one update the board but not the other does not? (function below)

```
// Inside Game component:

function handleClickToSelectPiece(clicked: string) {
    setCurrSelectedPiece(clicked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newDisplay = currDisplay;
newDisplay[squareID] = currSelectedPiece;
setCurrDisplay(newDisplay);
```

You are mutating the existing state instead of creating a new one. When you call `setCurrDisplay(newDisplay);`, react compares the old and new state, sees that they're the same object, and so it thinks nothing has changed. Since nothing changed, it does not rerender.

Instead, make a copy of the state, and modify that:

```
const newDisplay = [...currDisplay];
// OR if it's a non-array object:
// const newDisplay = { ...currDisplay };
newDisplay[squareID] = currSelectedPiece;
setCurrDisplay(newDisplay);
```

[Relevant section of react documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-the-screen-doesnt-update)